# Ошибка "нет значения" при запросе на обновление данных в БД

Tags: c#, sql, ms-access

Пытаюсь редактировать данные в БД, но пишет, что "нет значения для одного или нескольких требуемых параметров". Была попытка и вводить значения, и просто записывать — результат один и тот же. От чего это может быть?

```cs
    private void button6_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {        
        try
        {
            connection.Open();
            OleDbCommand command = new OleDbCommand();
            command.Connection = connection;
            string query =
                "UPDATE Marc SET Marcstud =@ln  Where IDSubject=@subject AND IDStudent=@student";

            //command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ln", Convert.ToInt32(textBox_m.Text));
            //command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@student", Convert.ToInt32(textBox_S.Text));
            //command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@subject", Convert.ToInt32(textBox_p.Text));

            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ln", 4);
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@student", 301);
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@subject", 101);


            MessageBox.Show(query);
            command.CommandText = query;

            command.ExecuteNonQuery();
            MessageBox.Show("data edit successful");
            connection.Close();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("error" + ex); ;
        }
    }
```

Таблица заполнена значениями. Обращаюсь к первой строке:

```
+-----------+-----------+------+
| IDSubject | IDStudent | Marc |
+-----------+-----------+------+
|       101 |       301 |    5 |
|       101 |       302 |    4 |
|       102 |       301 |    4 |
|       102 |       302 |    5 |
|       103 |       301 |    5 |
|       103 |       302 |    4 |
+-----------+-----------+------+
```

[image: Структура БД]

Comment: Структуру таблицы покажите. Последний раз когда был подобный вопрос оказалось, что в запросе не правильно указано имя колонки из таблицы а к передаваемым параметрам ошибка отношения не имела

Comment: добавила ,посмотрите пожалуйста

Comment: Проше всего этот запрос на обновление проверить на правильность в самом Access, да и вообще любой др. запрос нужный в программе сначала проверяйте в Access, а потом уже в код вставляйте.

Comment: А вот тут https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.data.oledb.oledbcommand.parameters(v=vs.110).aspx сказано, что OLE DB не поддерживает именованные параметры. И там же приведен пример как параметры добавлять. А еще мне кажется, что текст запроса стоит привязывать к command до того как начали добавлять параметры. хотя конечно не факт

Answer (score 0):

```
public void Update(String connectionString)
{
    var ln = Convert.ToInt32(textBox_m.Text);
    var student = Convert.ToInt32(textBox_S.Text);
    var subject = Convert.ToInt32(textBox_p.Text);

    using (var connection = new OleDbConnection(connectionString))
    {
        using (var command = connection.CreateCommand())
        {
            command.CommandText = "UPDATE Marc SET Marcstud = @ln Where IDSubject = @subject AND IDStudent = @student;";
            command.Parameters.AddRange(new OleDbParameter[]
            {
                new OleDbParameter("@ln", ln),
                new OleDbParameter("@student", student),
                new OleDbParameter("@subject", subject)
            });

            connection.Open();
            command.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: В комментариях к вопросу сказано: OleDB не поддерживает именованные параметры - проблема в этом.

Comment: @Alexander Petrov, можно делать из именованными параметрами, просто дальше на уровне OLEDB они игнорируются и подстановка идет в порядке следования параметров в массиве.